# How many different bending types could a non-Avatar master?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Title. I've always wondered how many elements someone not an avatar could master. It is implied in the show that only the Avatar could master all 4 elements and that bending is a skill that one was born with. Is it possible for someone to bend both air/fire, or any other combination of elements?

Comment: As many as the lion turtles would have granted their previous incarnations.

Comment: See also [Bending two elements](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/75787/bending-two-elements?rq=1)